# Need to free memory after Modal Segues, but I need both my Segues to pass data from A to B and B to A

Tags: swift, memory, modal-dialog, segue, viewcontroller

I am making a game for iOS with SpriteKit.

I have 2 Viewcontrollers. One is the GameViewController and the other one is the MenuViewController. Let's call them A and B respectively.

When the player dies, a function is called in GameScene.swift that launches a modal "Lost" Segue to B. There, the player can restart the game or buy a life and a "Back" Segue is called to A.

I need to dismiss the additional Views that get created each time I call a segue.

Problem is: I need the "Lost" Segue to send data about the Score to View B and I need the "Back" Segue to send data to View A about wether or not the player used a life.

I have implemented all this. But now I need to find how to dismiss old views that keep eating the device's memory, thus leading to lag and crash.

I have googled for hours and hours. No solution was adapted to my situation.

The solutions I found either caused my app to bug, data not to be passed or views not to be generated.

I will not add code here since there is a LOT. But I am sure the answer is actually really easy, just not for a beginner like me.

I think a possible solution would be an unwind segue from B to A ?

But do unwind segues pass data along ?

Moreover, I found no answer I could understand on how to use an unwind segue.

I exhausted all my possibilities. Stack Exchange is my last chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely should use an *unwind segue* to return to the previous viewController, otherwise as you have found your memory usage increases until your apps quits.

I created the following example from your description.  It uses a standard segue to move from the **GameViewController** to the **MenuViewController** and it uses an *unwind segue* to move from the **MenuViewController** back to the **GameViewController**.

The **GameViewController** has a *Player Dies* `UIButton`, a `UITextField` for entering a score, and a `UILabel` for displaying the lives.

The **MenuViewController** has a `UILabel` for showing the score, a *Buy a Life* `UIButton` for adding lives, and a *Restart* `UIButton` for returning to the **GameViewController**.

[image: storyboard overview]

Here's the code:

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var livesLabel: UILabel!

    var lives = 3

    func updateLivesLabel() {
        livesLabel.text = "Lives: \(lives)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateLivesLabel()
    }

    // This is the function that the unwind segue returns to.
    // You can call it anything you want, but it has to be in
    // the viewController you are returning to, it must be tagged
    // with @IBAction and it must take a UIStoryboardSegue as its
    // only parameter.
    @IBAction func returnFromMenu(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        print("We're back in GameViewController")

        // Update the lives label based upon the value passed in
        // prepareForSegue from the MenuViewController.
        updateLivesLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func goPlayerDies(sender: UIButton) {
        lives--
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Lost", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Lost" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MenuViewController
            destinationVC.score = Int(scoreTextField.text ?? "") ?? 0
            destinationVC.lives = lives
        }
    }
}
```

**MenuViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var score = 0
    var lives = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    }

    @IBAction func buyLife(sender: UIButton) {
        lives++
    }

    @IBAction func goRestart(sender: UIButton) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Back", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Back" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! GameViewController
            destinationVC.lives = lives
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is how you wire up the forward segue to be called programmatically:

<kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from *ViewController* icon to the *MenuViewController*:

[image: control drag to set up segue]

---

Select *Present Modally* from the pop-up:

[image: picture of pop-up]

---

Click on the *segue arrow* between the viewControllers and give it an identifier in the *Attributes Inspector*:

[image: identifier in attributes inspector]

---

This is how you wire up the *unwind segue* to be called programmatically:

<kbd>Control</kbd>-drag from *ViewController* icon to *Exit* icon:

[image: set up unwind segue]

---

Choose *returnFromMenu* from pop-up:

[image: choose return from Menu]

---

Click on the *Unwind Segue* in the *Document Outline* and give it the identifier *"Back"* in the *Attributes Inspector* on the right:

[image]

---

**Alternate Answer**

Instead of using *segues*, you can present and dismiss viewControllers manually.  The advantage for your app is that the **MenuViewController** will be allocated only once and will persist for the life of the app.  This same viewController will be presented and dismissed repeatedly, but it will not be deallocated which I suspect is leading to your crashes.

The **GameViewController** will be the initialViewController that is created by the Storyboard.  The **MenuViewController** will be loaded in `viewDidLoad` of the **GameViewController**.

To make this work, you need to add an identifier to the MenuViewController so that it can be instantiated by name.  Click on the MenuViewController in the Storyboard and set its **Storyboard ID** in the *Identity Inspector*:

[image: set storyboard ID]

---

Here is the code.  Note that all mention of segues is gone.  Note how `viewWillAppear` is used to update the viewControllers.

**GameViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var livesLabel: UILabel!

    var menuViewController: MenuViewController?

    var lives = 3

    func updateLivesLabel() {
        livesLabel.text = "Lives: \(lives)"
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        menuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        updateLivesLabel()
    }

    @IBAction func goPlayerDies(sender: UIButton) {
        lives--
        menuViewController?.score = Int(scoreTextField.text ?? "") ?? 0
        menuViewController?.lives = lives
        self.presentViewController(menuViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

**MenuViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MenuViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!

    var score = 0
    var lives = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        scoreLabel.text = "Score: \(score)"
    }

    @IBAction func buyLife(sender: UIButton) {
        lives++
    }

    @IBAction func goRestart(sender: UIButton) {
        let destinationVC = self.presentingViewController as! GameViewController
        destinationVC.lives = lives
        self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: You, Sir, are amazing ! Thank you ^^

Comment: Argh, just after implementing my unwind segue, I get an error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33725389/exc-bad-access-code-1-tried-nszombies-with-no-success @vacawama

Comment: There's probably nothing wrong with the unwind segue itself, but remember that the MenuViewController will be deallocated when you go back, so if there is anything hanging around there trying to access that memory after you leave, it will crash.  You wouldn't have that problem when you were allocating view controllers both direction but as you know that causes problems as well.

Comment: Check out my **Alternate Answer**.  It doesn't use segues at all which are proving problematic for your app.  It goes old school and instantiates and presents the MenuViewController manually.

Comment: It doesn't work. I need to implement the movement from View A to B in my died() function which is in my GameScene.swift

Comment: I updated my question this time with my full code for the 2 ViewControllers.

Comment: When I run my code with this new configurstion you suggested, I get an exception break point at :  menuViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MenuViewController") as? MenuViewController

Comment: Also, found a way to call a playerDies() with the necessary code in my GameViewController function from my GameScene.swift when the player dies

Comment: I get a EXC BAD INSTRUCTION at self.presentViewController(menuViewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: My mistake.  You need to set the **Storyboard ID** to `"MenuViewController"` in the *Identity Inspector*.  See updated answer with new picture.

Comment: Now all works. Except the life IAP. Now, when I purchase it, it suddenly tells me it was already purchased and restores it for free. On top of that, after that is done, the MenuViewController doesn't go back to my GameViewController and I have to click restart which means the life isn't even used at all. Very weird.

Comment: Especially since the life IAP is a consumable.

Comment: The console tells me this: IAP is enabled, loading...
     Product Request
     Product Added
     vonleheneck.iap.buykeepon
    Keep on
    Keep on increasing your score without having to restart from 0.
    1

    Buy: vonleheneck.iap.buykeepon
    Add Payment
    nil
    default: Error

Comment: It seems there exists no transaction suddenly. And I don't know why.

Comment: IAP can be considered a different issue I suppose. So thank you for helping me on this question. I approved your answer for this question and created a new one for the IAP issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741619/my-iap-isnt-working-bugs-at-func-paymentqueue