# Unwind segue WITHOUT Storyboards using Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue, unwind-segue

I can't seem to find a solution for this problem. All topics on unwind segues that I've found implement the segue via storyboards.

I am trying to learn how to make my layouts *purely* in code. So in my new Xcode projects, I am deleting the storyboard file.

I want to do an unwind segue on a view controller of mine that logs a user into the home screen of my app. When the user successfully logs in, the view should unwind.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this effect using only code?

Comment: See the 2nd half of this answer (first half is segues, 2nd half is without segues) http://stackoverflow.com/a/33716102/1630618

Comment: Hey thanks, this worked but with an additional line. My presenting view controller is a nav controller not it's root view controller which in my case is what I want to get back to and have it's values changed before the dismissViewController method completes. I did destinationVC = navController.viewControllers[0] to get it to work

Comment: Sounds good. You might also want to google delegation. A more proper division is for the called VC not to know anything about the caller (like its class). You achieve this by defining a protocol that the caller implements. You set a reference to the caller in the callee before you pushed the callee.  The reference is a weak pointer with the type of the protocol.  You call protocol methods on the delegate pointer to pass back data.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you so much, I looked up how to implement delegation and it achieves my desired results and now I know that this is the proper way to do this task. Your comments basically answered my question!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 7):

You can't do any "segue" action without segues which are storyboard items.

If the view you want to transition to is the first view on the navigation stack, you can use `self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)`

If you just want to go to another view controller, you can use

```
presentViewController
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also [`dismissViewControllerAnimated`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:), if the current view controller was presented modally.